# What is the different between a stackoverflow and arrayindexoutofbounds?

Tags: java, arrays, stack-overflow

It seems like in reality these should be almost identical. You are referencing or sticking data where it shouldn't go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`StackOverflowError`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StackOverflowError.html) occurs during endless recursive calls. It has nothing to do with arrays. [`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html) occurs when when you try to use an index beyond the size of the array.

Comment: What I mean is this. Isn't the end result almost the same?

Comment: the end result is a `Throwable` being thrown. But this is the same for all throwables (not that `StackoverflowError` isn't even an Exception)

Comment: How does Java know when it is a stackoverflow?

Comment: when you use deep recursion, a method gets invoked multiple times and fills the method call stack. Then it overflows.

Comment: Java knows it is a `StackOverflow` because... when it is a StackOverflow, the stack overflows. This doesn't happen when an array is indexed out of bounds. When an array is indexed out of bounds, there was code that tries to index into an array, and the index is out of bounds (not valid). Note that indexing an array is not trying to put more into it. When the stack overflows, there was code that tries to put more data on the stack. Note that putting data on the stack is not the same as trying to index into it - it's a stack, after all, not an array.

Answer (score 3):

**StackOverFlowError:**
 Occurs when the JVM ([Java Virtual Memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Virtual_Machine)) is running out of allocated heap space.

**ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:** 
 Occurs when an application tries to access the array index which does not fall in declared range.

Comment: Not heap, but stack. There is OutOfMemoryError for the heap.

Answer (score 3):

These two are actually very different things. As the other guys have already mentioned, ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException is an Exception that occurs when you are trying to access an array using an incorrect index. This could be caused by a very simple bug in programming logic.

StackOverflowError is something more low-level. It has nothing to do with arrays and, contrary to what the other guys said, has nothing to do with the heap either. Try doing that trick with a List and you'll get an OutOfMemoryError instead. Now it's an Error that is much more similar to StackOverflowError than ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. Both OutOfMemoryError and StackOverflowError indicate that you're running out of memory, only in different segments. Running out of stack memory almost always occurs due to infinite recursion (unless you have a ridiculously long chain of methods calling each other with lots of local variables in them), and running out of heap memory happens when you allocate too much and keep all those references so even the garbage collector can't free some memory for you.

So when ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException is indeed "sticking data where it shouldn't go", StackOverflowError and OutOfMemoryError are better described as "running out of memory to stick your data into".

Answer (score 2):

arrayindexoutofbounds : The exception that is thrown when an attempt is made to read beyond the bounds of an array.

stackoverflow : An error that is issued when a stack overflow occurs.

Answer (score 0):

**Arrayindexoutofbounds:** You limit your variable for example defining an array with size of 50 and if you want to use the 51. element of that array you get this exception.

**Stackoverflow:** Think about that you didn't limit your variable for example;

```
List myList = new List();
```

And you are adding elements to this list.

```
myList.add(something);
```

If you add too much element that your heap memory can't allocate any more space to keep your variable it throws that exception.

At first your limit is 50, at 51 you get an exception, at second you don't get an exception at 51. element if your heap is free enough but you can get an exception when your heap not enough for you.

Comment: You'll get OutOfMemoryError in such case since objects aren't allocated on the stack.